# how to Enable/disable javascript at certain height

Tags: javascript

How can I **enable/disable** `javascript` at certain height/point of the page?

I want to make `javascript` work when the top of the screen is between eg.: 2000px and 3000px otherwise it is disabled.

Comment: please include an example of [what you've tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com), and go into more detail about what you mean by "height of the page". Are you referring to the height of the contents of the page? Are you referring to the height of the browser window? Are you referring to a scroll position? As this question is currently unclear it's unanswerable, and therefor should be closed.

Comment: Removing `enable-if` tag which is for something else.

Comment: Well I'm working on [this project][http://codepen.io/sviweb/pen/NAXdKZ0], but I can't make it work properly. I have figured out, how to pin up the slider, but still cant resolve how to make some kind of trigger, which will that start sliding when it pinned and finish when the pin is released...

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it's not *java script*, it's *javascript*. Javascript has nothing to do with java, except that the syntax is a little bit similar.

Enabling or disabling javascript is impossible for the script itself. What you can do is check the window size, set a boolean if javascript should be disabled and check this variable whenever a function is executed:

```js
function getWindowWidth() {
    return window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.body.clientWidth;
}
function getWindowHeight() {
    return window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight || document.body.clientHeight;
}

var jsEnabled = (getWindowWidth() > 1000);

if (window.addEventListener) {
    window.addEventListener("resize", function() {
        jsEnabled = (getWindowWidth() > 1000);
    };
} else {
    window.attachEvent("onresize", function() {
        jsEnabled = (getWindowWidth() > 1000);
    }
}

function someFunc() {
    // Here's the magic!
    if (!jsEnabled) return;

    doStuff();
    otherStuff();
}
```

Comment: "except that the syntax is a little bit similar" -- this is not true. The reason it's called JavaScript is because [it was renamed from LiveScript on Netscape when it also released support for Java technology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript#Beginnings_at_Netscape). The languages are in no way similar to each other whatsoever, just that its name was influenced by Oracle as a marketing ploy.

Comment: Saying the syntax is similar is misleading. You seem to be suggesting that's the reason their names are similar, which is why I corrected the statement in the first place.

Comment: Yes it might have been misleading, but you have to agree that java syntax and javascript syntax have some similarities, more than javascript has with PHP, Python, Ruby, Pascal or Perl.

Comment: I agree with Aloso that the syntax is fairly similar to the simple java though mostly have nothing common.
but back to my question. I'm working now on this project: http://codepen.io/sviweb/pen/NAXdKZ but I cant make to start the slider work at the point when it is pinned, and finish the slide show when the pin is released